# Open UIViewController from UIWebView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, uiviewcontroller

I'm wondering if i can do the following,

I wanna Load and view a `UIViewController` When i click on button inside a `UIWebView`, how can i get the `UIWebView` action and read it in the app ?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

implement [webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3ashouldStartLoadWithRequest%3anavigationType%3a) in your code

see "communicating back with Objective-C code" [here](http://www.codingventures.com/2008/12/using-uiwebview-to-render-svg-files/)